# New file for each instance creation

Tags: python, file, static-variables

I have a class that needs to write to a file.  My program creates multiple of these classes and I want to avoid write collisions.  I tried to avoid it by using a static variable so each class has a unique file name. ie:

```
class Foo:
    instance_count = 1

    @staticmethod
    def make():
        file_name = Foo.instance_count + '-' + 'file.foo'
        Foo.instance_count += 1
        Foo(file_name)

    def Foo(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
```

This works to some extent but doesn't work in cases where the class may be created in parallel.  How can I make this more robust?

**EDIT**:
My use case has this class being created in my app, which is served by gunicorn.  So I launch my app with gunicorn, with lets say 10 workers, so I can't actually manage the communication between them.

Comment: Actually, can you explain your use case a little more: When you say in parallel, how exactly you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just use another text file to keep the filenames and the number/code you need to identify. You can use JSON, pickle, or just your own format.

In the `__init__` function, you can read to your file. Then, make a new file based on the information you get.

File example:

```
File1.txt,1
Fil2e.txt,2
```

And the `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self):
    counter = int(open('counter.txt', 'r').read()[-2:].strip())
    with open("File%d.txt"%counter+1, "w"):
         #do things
    #don't forget to keep the information of your new file
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same problem of them trying to read from the counter.txt at the same time?

Comment: @riotburn Not exactly so, except they are created on an exactly same time. They'll use different files when working.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of something like [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) instead if unique name is what you are after.

EDIT:

If you would want readable but unique names, I would suggest you to look into guarding your increment statement above with a lock so that only one process is increasing it at any point of time and also perhaps make the file creation and the increment operation atomic.

Comment: @riotburn i added a suggestion above.

Comment: While this is a good answer, in my case the class creation comes from spawning multiple workers through gunicorn, so not sure how I could make them communicate.

Comment: I think you will have to use a solution which combines mutexes and a persistent storage (a file as @allKid suggests) where the last filename created is written to.

Answer (score 0):

Really what I was looking for was a way to avoid write contention.  Then I realized why not just use the logger. Might be a wrong assumption, but I would imagine the logger takes care of locking files for writing.  Plus it flushes on every write, so it meets that requirement.  As for speed, the overhead definitely does not affect me in this case.

The other solution I found was to use the tempfile class.  This would create a unique file for each instantiation of the class.

```
import tempfile as tf

class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def make():
        file_name = tf.NamedTemporaryFile('w+',suffix="foofile",dir="foo/dir")
        Foo(file_name)

    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
```